# How can I deal with the Nuke Bombers?

Tags: empire-earth

In Empire Earth 2 the AI (and most players) invest heavily in nuke bombers if allowed to get to that tech era.  Not just one bomber either, 3-10 nuke bombers.

How can I effectively deal with the bombers?

Are there any unique structures that will help?

Answer (score 2):

Just invest in more bombers than they do... works every time :-)

Alternatively, you can invest in air defense units. You can only have a handful (6 i believe) per area, but they are a lot easier to get than boombers. I just make sure to have at least one built as soon as the nuclear epoch approaches.

The anti-aircraft units are also a good investment, but they're pretty expensive. They are amazing.. not only because they seem to have a higher hit rate, but they can be moved around (unlike air defense).

Comment: Pretty much. 

Global thermonuclear war... whoever loses the least wins.

Answer (score 1):

Offence is the best defense.

Build more nuclear bombers and finish off the opponent.

But if you really want to defend, identify the direction in which the bombers approach your air space and pack the route with any kind of anti air units available. Whenever you reach the age of nuclear bombers, it is better to double your anti air guns and provide good defense for these guns as they too will be targeted.